# Mongodb: Get last item from array in document

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB with elements looking like this

```
{
  userId: 'X',
  access: [
    { deviceId: 'a', time: "A timestamp" },
    { deviceId: 'b', time: "Another timestamp" },
  ]
}
```

I want to match documents based on userId and then I want to get the last element in the access array. The value I am most interested in here for user with id "X" is "Another timestamp".

I do not want mongodb to return the entire document, just that last element and always the last one.

How can I write a query/aggregation that solves this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$slice`:

```
db.collection.find({ userId: 'value' }, { access: { $slice: -1 } } )
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not know slice could be used like that with find.